# why is the layout of my website different on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple website for a homework.

[image]

This is how the site looks like on google chrome.

At first, I used px instead of '%' for my website, then changed it because turned out it looked different on different browsers. After I used '%', I was satisfied because it looked the same, but then I tried to open it on my phone's google chrome and this is how it looks

[image]

I tried using the meta viewport, but that only made it worse. All the element overlaps with each other. My friends didn't use any media queries and their sites still looked alright on both mobile and desktop (fonts looked smaller and everything, but the layout was still alright).

here's the css code:

```css
    <style>
        .header{
            background-image: url("https://www.blibli.com/friends/assets/masakan-indonesia-featured-696x464.jpg");
            position: absolute;
            height: 25%;
            width: 99%;
            text-align: center;
            filter: blur(2px);
            -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
        }

        .headertext{
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            font-size: 4.5em;
            top: 7%;
            left: 28%;
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            z-index: 1;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
        .topnav {
            background-color: chocolate;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            width: 99%;
            top: 26.5%;
        }

        /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 1% 9.92%;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 1.373em;
            font-family: Roboto;
        }

        /* Change the color of links on hover */
        .topnav a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
        .topnav a.active {
            color: white;
        }

        /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        .sidebar{
            width: 20%;
            height: 107%;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            top: 40%;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: rgba(148, 145, 141, 0.37);
        }

        .main{
            width: 76.3%;
            height: 220%;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            left: 23%;
            background-color: rgba(148, 145, 141, 0.37);
        }

        .box{
            border:1px solid red;
            position:absolute;
            width:80%;
            height:22%;
            left: 5%;
            transition: 0.2s;
        }

        .box:hover{
            transform: scale(1.05);
        }

        .top{
            top: 3%;
        }

        .middle{
            position: absolute;
            top: 31%;

        }

        .bottom{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:19%
        }

        .picture{
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 50%;
            height: 85%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 7.5%;
            left: 3%;
        }

        .text {
            width: 40%;
            height: 80%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 7.5%;
            right: 4%;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        .judul{
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            font-size: 1.6em;
            line-height: 2;
            letter-spacing: 0.3em;
        }

        .link{
            bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 0.7em;
        }

        .button{
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 1.5% 10%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 7%;
            left: 35%;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }

        .button:hover{
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }

        .more{
            background-color: chocolate;
            color: white
        }

        .rekomendasi{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 96%;
            height: 5%;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            padding: 2%;
            background-color: chocolate;
            text-align: center;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
            color: white;
        }

        .rekomendasicontent{
            position: absolute;
            top: 85%;
            font-size: 0.6em;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: Roboto;
            letter-spacing: 0em;
            color: black;
            line-height: 160%;
        }

        .populer{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            top: 49%;
            width: 96%;
            height: 5%;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            padding: 2%;
            background-color: chocolate;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .populercontent{
            font-size: 0.6em;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: Roboto;
            letter-spacing: 0em;
            position: absolute;
            top:85%;
            color: black;
            line-height: 160%;
        }

        .link2{
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: none;
        }

        li{
            transition: 0.2s;
        }

        li:hover{
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }

        .footer{
            width: 97.8%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 260%;
            background-color: chocolate;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 1em;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.5%;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you sized everything as a percentage of the width and then made the width much smaller?

Comment: `position: absolute` is very rarely the correct approach to positioning elements. There are _much_ better solutions these days. Research [Flex Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout), [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) and [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: true. but i tried px and it looked different on edge and chrome. i wanna know if there's a way to bridge this.

Comment: @Turnip i tried relative, but no matter how much i set the value of the top, bottom, and left properties, nothing changed

Comment: Exactly. So research the technologies I mentioned and build a modern layout.

Comment: The `position` property is useful for very specialised small parts of layouts. It is rarely useful for large scale layouts.

Comment: Yes, It's simple, but you have to know modern CSS layouts like flexbox, CSS Grid, and column-based layout. I suggest you explore this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJZv4d5rbIKd4QHMPkcABCw) channel and [Freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tag/css/)